# Toggle on partial text

Tags: jquery, toggle

Dear StackOverflow friends,
I'd like to apply the Js effect I found on this site
goo.gl/F89yQX

in order to show full text after clicking on "Read more", and reducing text after clicking on "Hide Text".

I found many similar questions on StackOverflow and Google, and in particoular this example 
jsfiddle.net/8SXNZ/1/

```
$('.term-description').on('click', function () {
$(this).toggleClass('open'); });
```

but I'm not able to modify it to my needs: I have to use it on a Wordpress site and I prefer to use a click on "Show/Hide text" string, exactly just it is on the first website I linked.

Here is my last attempt
http://jsfiddle.net/leonardinha/hybvR/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".more_custom").click(function() {
    $(".term-description").slideToggle(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $(".more_custom").text("Extend >>");
        }
        else {
            $(".more_custom").text("Reduce >>");
        }
    });
}); });
```

but the problem I can't solve is that the full text never appears. 
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I am pulling your answer out of the question and posting it here for future users:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/jquery.expander.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('div.readmore').expander({
            slicePoint: 200,
            expandText: 'Click Here to Read More',
            userCollapseText: 'Hide Text'
        });
    });
</script>
```

This was found on [devcurry.com](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/add-read-more-link-using-jquery.html)